# Retrieve block execution time using GCC or ifort

Tags: optimization, gcc, profiling, fortran, benchmarking

**[gprof -A](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Annotated-Source.html#Annotated-Source)** gives execution times (how many times, a unitless number). **[gcov](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov.html) -b** gives percentages within each block ("first line in this loop took 77% of its execution time"). Potential options involving ifort would be acceptable: [codecov](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/fortran/win/optaps/common/optaps_pgo_covr.htm) is available, with similar functionality. The Internet seems silent about means to measure loop execution time ("this look took 16% of this function execution time")...

Comment: Did you consider also [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Have you considered using the intrinsic subroutine [cpu_time](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/CPU_005fTIME.html#CPU_005fTIME)? While not a profiling tool & requires (potentially significant) additions to your current code, it definitely will give you loop execution times.

Comment: If you have the money Intel VTune (http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) offers a multitude of timing information which may meet your needs.

Comment: How much precision do you need? If you use a stack sampler like [*Zoom*](http://www.rotateright.com/) the percent of stack samples that pierce that loop is the number you want. If you only need low precision, you can [*take the samples by hand under `gdb`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).